# How do I validate form with multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

So I have a registration form with three tabs. The first tab is where a user can enter `email`, `password` and `confirm password` and the second tab is their details such as address,mobile number,state,etc and a third tab where the user can have to agree on T&C and provide a digital signature.

I can switch on either tabs however I like without filling in some fields but when I click on the sign up button (in the third tab), it should perform a client-side validation to  make sure all fields are keyed in and password/confirm password are matched. Any of the fields not displaying should notify the user for example.

Code:

```
 <div>
        <div class="card border-rounded-0 bg-bujishu-gold guests-card">
            <h5 class="text-center bujishu-gold form-card-title">Registration</h5>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link register-tab-active active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#registration" role="tab" aria-controls="registration" aria-selected="true">Registration</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link register-tab-active" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#information" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Information</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link register-tab-active" id="agreement-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#agreement" role="tab" aria-controls="agreement" aria-selected="false">Agreement</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="card-body">

                <!-- Dealer Registration Form -->
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                        <!-- Registration  Tab-->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="registration" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="registration-tab">
                            <h5 class="text-center" style="background-color: #303030; color: #ffffff; padding: .5rem; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">Account Particulars</h5>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required id="email" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required id="password">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="password-confirm">Confirm Password</label>
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Next Button -->
                            <div class="text-right">
                                <!-- <a class="btn btn-secondary next-button" id="information-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#information" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Next</a> -->
                                <a class="btn btn-secondary next-button">Next</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Information Tab -->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="information" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="information-tab">
                            <!-- Personal Particulars -->
                            <h5 class="text-center" style="background-color: #303030; color: #ffffff; padding: .5rem; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">Personal Particulars</h5>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="full_name">Full Name (as per NRIC)</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="full_name" class="form-control" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="nric">NRIC Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="nric" class="form-control" id="nric" placeholder="NRIC Number">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="address_1">Address Line 1</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="address_1" id="address_1" class="form-control" placeholder="Residential Address Line 1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="address_1">Address Line 2</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="address_2" id="address_2" class="form-control" placeholder="Residential Address Line 1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="address_1">Address Line 3</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="address_3" id="address_3" class="form-control" placeholder="Residential Address Line 1">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="city">City</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label for="state">State</label>
                                    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                                        <option disabled selected>Choose your state..</option>
                                        @foreach($states as $state)
                                        <option class="text-capitalize" value="{{ $state->id }}">{{ $state->name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="contact_number_home">Contact Number (Home)</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="contact_number_home" class="form-control" placeholder="Home Contact Number">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="contact_number_mobile">Contact Number (Mobile)</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="contact_number_mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Contact Number">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <label style="display: block;" for="existing_customer_options">Are you an existing Destiny Code customer?</label>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="existing_customer" value="0" checked>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="existing_customer">No</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="existing_customer" value="1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="existing_customer">Yes</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Next Button -->
                            <div class="text-right">
                                <!-- <a class="btn btn-secondary next-button" id="agreement-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#agreement" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Next</a> -->
                                <a class="btn btn-secondary next-button">Next</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I tried using `required` on the inputs but does not seem to do anything. From what I see, it seems like jQuery is the only option left but I wonder is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you should not allow user to go to next step without validating first step's data.

Comment: Check out validate.js https://validatejs.org/

Comment: Honestly you should use a server side code to validate as JS can be disabled.

Comment: I mean I want to validate on both sides, client and server side. Right now I am working on client side first.

Comment: @hussain.codes Yes, How do I do that?

Comment: @LordJesus each step will have next button, on when user clicks on next button trasition to next step only if entered data is validated. if not then show validation error messages.

Comment: How will the code look like?

Answer (score 1):

I’m on my phone so your code is basically unreadable cause of weird phone formatting. What you could do is make it so that, when you switch tabs, you’re actually just making some hidden elements show and some elements hide within the same form. This would be very easy to do in JavaScript. Then you can set all of them to required and tada. Not 100% sure if this works but I think it will. Make sure you use the html hidden attribute and not the css display none.

Comment: Problem is there is a register tab form above too

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of validation with JQuery for matching passwords.
I am setting a function with `.keyup(function(){})` then I am setting a conditional that checks the value of each id tag and if they do not match I am returning an error message with red color and bg to user warning of the non match, I am also disabling the submit button so they can not submit the form until they fix the issue. Then if there is a match I am return a success message with green color and bg and removing the disabled attribute so the form can be submitted.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Validation form to a DB or for login should be done in backend, not the front end. Front end should only be used as a first step to validation. Keep in mind that JS can be disabled and make your validation worthless. Use PHP or ASP to do final validations!

```js
$("#password").keyup(function() { // we fire on the keyup event
    //compare the values of the two passwords using .val() and their ids        
    if ($("#password").val() != $("#confirm_password").val()) {  

      // if they do not match we add an error message to the div #msg
      // we also remove potential latent classes and add new class to get warning font color and bg color
      $("#msg").html("Passwords do not match").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert alert-danger");
      // disable and style the submit button using .prop() and remove/addClass()
      $("#enter").prop('disabled', true);
      $("#enter").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert alert-danger");
    } else {
      // On success we add success msg and switch styles to note success in green
      $("#msg").html("Passwords matched").removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert alert-success");
      // Turn the submit back on by removing the disabled attr
      $("#enter").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#enter").removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert alert-success");
    }
  });
  //rinse and repeat for the #confirm-password tag
  $("#confirm_password").keyup(function() {
    if ($("#password").val() != $("#confirm_password").val()) {
      $("#msg").html("Passwords do not match").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert alert-danger");
      $("#enter").prop('disabled', true);
      $("#enter").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert alert-danger");
    } else {
      $("#msg").html("Passwords matched").removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert alert-success");
      $("#enter").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#enter").removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert alert-success");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<label for="usr_password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="usr_password" placeholder="PASSWORD" required>
</div>
<label for="confirm_password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <input class="form-control" id="confirm_password" type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="CONFIRM PASSWORD" required>
</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Enter Password" id="enter">
```

Comment: Your code is pretty confusing. I feel like I should just validate each page

Comment: I strongly suggest you scour the web for examples of each validation you need and wrap your head around how it works. Pretty straight forward really, get the val of an input, compare it to a reg ex or other rule then let the user know what they need to do to fix and/or disable/enable elements if needed.